# Fetching external data from localhost node.js server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and all I simply want to do is fetch data for the public github api and log it when I run node. Here's the very simple example:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

var PORT = 5001;

request('https://api.github.com/users/someUser**', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); 
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on PORT:',PORT);
});
```

and then, I'm running `node program.js` to start the server. Then, I'm always getting an error that includes:

```
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the way I am going about it or setting things up? All I want to do is simply do is fetch some external data from my localhost server. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is because `user-agent` is required you can check the documentation in the following [link](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required)
so you should pass it in the header of your request so the code should be as following:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

var PORT = 5001;

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/users/someuser',
  headers:  { 'User-Agent': 'Awesome-Octocat-App', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response.statusCode );
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    console.log(body);
});


app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on PORT:',PORT);
});
```